# How to integrate Qt in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, qtquick2

I install latest version of Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.
 I want to integrate Qt in Eclipse IDE.
 How I can do that.I do not have QT install on my PC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how well it works, but there's a guide on the Qt Wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Eclipse_on_Linux

I'd personally say that Qt Creator is a lot better than Eclipse when it comes to building Qt applications, especially if you want to do anything with Designer files.

Comment: Is Qt Creator is free?If I go for Qt Creator Will I able to use C++ in that

Comment: Yes, Qt Creator is a free download and you can use it for C++. It's predominately setup for working with Qt infused C++, but you can use it for generic C++ as well.

Comment: It's completely cross platform, so will work with your Windows 7 machine.

Comment: After complete installation it is showing 30 day trial version.ask for buying please guide me.

Comment: You've most likely downloaded the Commercial version, you should download the open source version instead.